# Unable to access the WSDL in WebLogic 12C

Tags: java, wsdl, weblogic, apache-axis, weblogic12c

We are facing the below exception when accessing the WSDL for one of our webapps on weblogic 12c.

```
<Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101020> <[ServletContext@1959382202[app:mywebapp module:mywebapp path:null spec-version:3.0]] Servlet failed with an Exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis2.wsdl.util.WSDLDefinitionWrapper cannot be cast to oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.DefinitionImpl
        at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLWriterImpl.writeWSDL(WSDLWriterImpl.java:87)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printDefinitionObject(AxisService.java:1085)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printUserWSDL(AxisService.java:1112)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printWSDL(AxisService.java:1386)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent.handleWSDLRequest(ListingAgent.java:327)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

When we try to hit the URL we see an error(contact the administrator) on the screen and the above exception in the logs.

Comment: It appears to be a known bug at Oracle. You should connect to My Oracle Support and download path for Bug 24399682